# In the Quarkus Amazon Lambda HTTP guide the Lambda runtime cannot find QuarkusStreamHandler on the classpath

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus

As this issue hasn't been raised already I'm obviously missing something simple. I am following the Quarkus - Amazon Lambda with Resteasy, Undertow, or Vert.x Web guide using the 1.0.0.Final release (I've also tried the CR and 0.28.1 releases).
I have this packaged as an Uber jar.
I have run the mvn quarkus-bootstrap:build-tree and this shows the io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-http-deployment:jar:1.0.0.Final with it's dependant jars and checking the generated runner jar shows that the io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.class file is present.
However, whenever I run this either in the AWS SAM environment or in AWS proper I get the dreaded `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler`
I'm at a loss where to turn. I'm compiling using Maven 3.6.2 and Graal 19.2.1 (though not the native compilation).

Comment: do you have project code you could share?  Your SAM template and pom.xml if nothing else might be helpful.

Comment: I made a mistake about AWS proper. This is working, however in SAM it isn't. I'm actually just running the test app generated from the maven archetype. I'm not sure if it's relevant but the environment is WSL Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: can you share you SAM template?  I'm about to go on holiday break (yeah, AMERICA!) but i'll try to look it over as I can.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles across this, I found that adding "quarkus.package.uber-jar=true" to application.properties folder is required when working with maven.

https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling